# Prove scaling does not affect Least Square solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I need to prove the that scaling x does not affect the prediction of Least Square solution. I think I need to prove the following equation, since scaling columns of X can be rewrite as multiplying a diagonal matrix W.

$$(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty \cdot x = ((WX)^T(WX))^{-1}(WX)^Ty \cdot (Wx)$$

Here $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n} $, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I know that r.h.s. can be rewritten as 
$$y^T(WX)((WX)^T(WX))^{-1}Wx$$
$$y^T(WX)(X^TWWX))^{-1}Wx$$

Any idea how I can prove they are equal. It seems to me that it's really hard to get this $W$ and $X$ out of the brackets, although it seems obvious that they should be equal, and it is always true for square matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Remark: A mistake correction: $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$. Otherwise the product $X^Ty$ is not compatible.

What you want to show is

$$(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.x=((XW)^T(XW))^{-1}(XW)^Ty.(Wx)$$

This can be shown as follows:

\begin{align}
((XW)^T(XW))^{-1}(XW)^Ty.(Wx)
&=(WX^TXW)^{-1}(WX^Ty).(Wx)\\
&=W^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}W^{-1}WX^Ty.(Wx)\\
&=W^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty.(Wx)\\
&=(W^{-1}(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)^T(Wx)\\
&=((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)^TW^{-1}(Wx)\\
&=((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)^T(x)\\
&=((X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty).x
\end{align}